# Can I passing the products data when payment is processed?

Tags: payment-gateway, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I want to store product information in qbo.
Which API use for record product information in qbo?
Like product name, description, etc...

Please anyone help me on this, how can I store products data when payment is processed.

```
$Payments = new QuickBooks_Payments($oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $sandbox);

$CreditCard = new QuickBooks_Payments_CreditCard($name, $number, $expyear, $expmonth, $address1, $city, $state, $postalcode, $country, $cvc);
```

Using above API I got status "CAPTURED" when charge the card.
And then using below API I recording customer:

```
$CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();
```

And then I used Payment API for record payment in qbo right:

```
$PaymentService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Payment();
// Create payment object
$recordPayment = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Payment();
```

Then I got complete response using below code:

```
// Send payment to QBO 
if ($response = $PaymentService->add($Context, $realm, $recordPayment)) {
    echo 'Our new Payment ID is: [' . $response . ']';
} else {
    echo '<p style="color: red">' . $PaymentService->lastError() . '</p>';
}
```

Now I want to record Product Details in QBO sandbox whatever customer bought when payment is proccessed.
That's it.

And one more thing:
I am tried to record product information using Account, Item API and I successfully record them but That information is not showing in Sandbox Account and It's show in ARRAY when I print.
Using below code:

For Account:

```
$AccountService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Account();

$Account = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Account();

$Account->setName('My Test Name');
$Account->setDescription('Here is my description');
$Account->setAccountType('Income');

if ($resp = $AccountService->add($Context, $realm, $Account))
{
    print('Our new Account ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
    print($AccountService->lastError());
}
```

For Item:

```
$ItemService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Item();

$Item = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Item();

$Item->setName('My Item');
$Item->setType('Inventory');
$Item->setIncomeAccountRef('53'); //It comes from account information

if ($resp = $ItemService->add($Context, $realm, $Item))
{
    print('Our new Item ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
    print($ItemService->lastError($Context));
}
```

Now I want to create sales receipt but I didn't understand How to use code for Sales Receipt.
That's it.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Please go review the QuickBooks developer documentation at developer.intuit.com, and learn how to use QuickBooks. This should then be very obvious. If you have actual programming-related questions, please try to post some code or show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Now, I added some code above @KeithPalmerJr.

Comment: anyone please help me on this.@KeithPalmerJr.

Comment: Start with the Invoice example. Change where you see Invoice to SalesReceipt. It's really that easy. Please post what you've tried if you are still having trouble.